# Auto resize content to fit screen based on monitor resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i'm using bootstrap 4 with some cards and i've came across a problem.

I made a page that looks perfectly fine on 1920x1080 resolution, but when my friend who uses a 2560x1440 resolution loaded the same page, it looked a bit different.

[image: screen test]

The left is 1920x1080 and the right is 2560x1440. As you can see, the 2560x1440 resolution has a huge gap of space at the bottom. It should look exactly like the image on the left but auto resized to fit the page.

```css
body {
  background-color: #5C67B6;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

#footer {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#clearfooter {
  height: 50px;
}

.card {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Added */
  float: none;
  /* Added */
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  /* Added */
}

.container {
  max-height: 1280px;
  max-width: 720px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h2 style="text-align: center; color:#fff;"><strong>Premium Offers</strong></h2>
<h4 style="text-align: center; color:#fff;">Choose your Plan</h4>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h3 class="card-title">Turbo</h3>
        <p class="card-text">If Turbo isn't enough for you, <br> you can upgrade to Turbo Plus.<br>
          <br>If you want to <strong>ALWAYS</strong> be ahead of competing servers, this is for you.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-inverse" style="width: 20rem; border-color: #fff;">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">Highlighted Server!</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Always visible!</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Special Support</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Turbo Plus role on our server</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Turbo Plus Badge</li>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item active" style="text-align: center;">Buy Turbo Plus</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card card-inverse" style="background-color: #333; border-color: #333; width: 20rem;">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h3 class="card-title">Turbo Plus</h3>
        <p class="card-text">If Turbo isn't enough for you, <br> you can upgrade to Turbo Plus.<br>
          <br>If you want to <strong>ALWAYS</strong> be ahead of competing servers, this is for you.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-inverse" style="width: 20rem; border-color: #333;">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">Highlighted Server!</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Always visible!</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Special Support</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Turbo Plus role on our server</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Turbo Plus Badge</li>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item active" style="text-align: center;">Buy Turbo Plus</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried looking for some answers with similar problems but with no avail. Would appreciate some help with this. Been working on this for 7-9 hours.

Comment: Just Advice:) if you made in middle part in center than it will goog

Comment: You are setting `max-height: 1280px;` and  `max-width: 720px;` on the container, yet you want the content to be "auto resized to fit the page"?

Comment: that's what someone with a similar problem was told to do. it didn't auto-scale with or without it either way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this would be to use the VW and VH properties, or convert every height parameter to percentages so that everything (even the fonts) resize, when changing the scale of the window. If you do proceed with adding even height in percentages then make sure to have the body and all the underlaying children set with a specific height.

For example setting everything on a percentage in height will result into the following: https://jsfiddle.net/y1kbz5r0/2/ (further edits to the height and what not is required).

Alternatively you could also work with media queries to enlarge certain sizes everything above 1080px in height, like:

```
@media screen and (min-height:1080px){
    //CSS code here
}
```

Edit: Further changes to the MediaQuery and with usage of VH can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/y1kbz5r0/4/

I hope this will provide you with enough information to proceed with this. If not feel free to ask for further information.

Edit: Worked out version as per your requirements:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
html,body{
 height:100%;
 width:100%
}
body{
 background-color:#5C67B6;
 margin:auto;
 position:relative;
 padding-top:10%;
}
header{
 margin:auto;
 padding:2vh 0;
 text-align:center;
 color:#fff;
}
.container{
 margin:auto;
 height:70%;
}
.card-deck{
 margin:auto;
}
.card{
 margin:1rem;
 min-width:20rem!important;
 width:30vw;
 font-size:1.2em
}
.card-inverse{
 background-color:#333; 
 border-color:#333;
}
.buybutton{text-align:center!important}
@media screen and (min-height:1000px){
 body{
  font-size:1.7vh
 }
 h2{font-size:3vh}
 h3{font-size:2.6vh}
 h4{font-size:2.2vh}
 .card,.card-inverse{
  width:33vw!important;
 }
 .container{
  display:flex;
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  margin:auto;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
 }
 .card-block{
  padding:1.6vh;
 }
 .card-deck{
  border-spacing:1.75vh 0;
 }
 .list-group-item{
  padding:1vh 1.65vh;
 }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <h2>Premium Offers</h2>
  <h4>Choose your Plan</h4>
 </header>
<!--Container-->
 <div class="container">
  <div class="card-deck">
   <!--Card One-->
   <div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
     <h3 class="card-title">Turbo</h3>
     <p class="card-text">If Turbo isn't enough for you,
      <br> you can upgrade to Turbo Plus.
      <br>
      <br>If you want to <strong>ALWAYS</strong> be ahead of competing servers, this is for you.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-inverse">
     <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Highlighted Server!</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Always visible!</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Special Support</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Turbo Plus role on our server</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Turbo Plus Badge</li>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item active buybutton">Buy Turbo Plus</a>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
   <!--Card Two-->
   <div class="card card-inverse">
    <div class="card-block">
     <h3 class="card-title">Turbo Plus</h3>
     <p class="card-text">If Turbo isn't enough for you,
      <br> you can upgrade to Turbo Plus.
      <br>
      <br>If you want to <strong>ALWAYS</strong> be ahead of competing servers, this is for you.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-inverse">
     <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">Highlighted Server!</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Always visible!</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Special Support</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Turbo Plus role on our server</li>
      <li class="list-group-item">Turbo Plus Badge</li>
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item active buybutton">Buy Turbo Plus</a>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Padding and margin tweaks might need to be changed further on to your liking, but I do think with this code, your question is pretty much answered.

Comment: every height parameter seems to be already using percentages except for the footer that isn't being used (forgot to remove it in the snippet)

Comment: It doesn't actually have any effect as the body doesn't have any set height value.

You have to set your body to height:100%, and all your children to actually have any effect with height in percentages.

Comment: For example: https://jsfiddle.net/y1kbz5r0/2/

Here the html, body,.container,.card-deck have all set to a percentage value, which then translate to the .card having a working height in percentage.

Also centering the cards by adding margin:auto to the card-deck class also helps a lot!

Comment: in your jsfiddle code if you zoom out, the whole card glitches. also, the min-height in the body can't be 100%, it has to be min-height:1280px; or else it'll slide sideways if zoomed in. i'll try to think of something based on the examples you gave me though.

Comment: it didn't fix it so i can't accept it. http://i.imgur.com/lehP9Vg.png it makes the cards look like this. And is no longer centered to the middle of the page when i use your code. note: (jsfiddle zooms it in by 160% it seems) it needs to look normal at 100%

Comment: if you could edit it so where it looks normal (non glitched like how it looks in the OP) while maintaining scaling for both resolutions, that'd be good. i will upvote your post in the meantime. i've been trying to figure this out all day and have a huge headache. so my apologies.

Comment: If you're referring to glitched like not having the large height difference then now I understand you in terms of "glitchiness". And yea I could look into it tomorrow probably and update the main code. I'll comment here when the main post is updated ;)

Comment: Thank you. Will be looking forward to your response with updated code.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142995/discussion-between-rafael-de-jongh-and-zezima we can continue the discussion here

Comment: Updated the main post, you might want to check if that works for you ;)